# Not able to render label tag on a view dynamically

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have below piece of code in `.cshtml` file.

```
<div class="row">

            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter POR ID" id="porID" class="col-md-2 input-sm" name="porTextBox">
            <button class="btn btn-primary col-md-2 btn-sm" style="margin-left:15px;width:150px;" type="submit" id="btnCreateTFSItems"><strong>Create TFS Items</strong></button>
            @if (TempData["formState"] != null)
            {
                //@Html.Label("lblsuccess", "Successfully created TFS Work Items!")
                <label id="lblsuccess" style="color:green; visibility:visible">   Successfully created TFS Work Items!</label>
            }
        </div>
```

and the button is calling the below function in script tag :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    $('#btnCreateTFSItems').click(function () {
        var txt = $('#porID');
        var errorLabel = $('#lblError');
        if (txt.val() != null && txt.val() != '') {
            //alert('clicked');

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("CreateWorkItems", "Tables")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { 'porTextBox': $('#porID').val() }
            });
           // alert('Successfully added');
        }
        else {
            errorLabel.text("Please enter valid PORID");
            return false;
        }
    });

    $("#porID").keypress(function (e) {
        var errorLabel = $('#lblError');
        errorLabel.text("");
        //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
        if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is in `.cshtml` file, it is checking the condition but its not adding the label. The reason may be because page is not refreshing to render the label. I am new to UI development so I have tried certain options which i found on net but wasn't able to make it work. Is there any way i can achieve this ?

Comment: What do you mean _not adding the label_? You set it to an empty string in the `keypress()` method (and only give it a value if your input is empty)

Comment: I have tried adding the label in a separate div below the button tag but still i am not able to assign the value to it.

Comment: What is the value of `TempData["formState"]` when the page is first rendered - if its `null` then the label will not even exist. Not clear what your trying to do here

Comment: its value is `'Created'`. This is just a check. I update the value of `TempData["formState"]` in the action itself and then checking it in the view. If its not null then i render that label. Before this , i used the same logic inside a `<Form>` tag and there it was working perfectly.

Comment: `public ActionResult CreateWorkItems(string porTextBox)
        {
            string poRTextBox = porTextBox.ToString();
            //int domePORID = int.Parse(porTextBox);
            //var featureWorkItemId = LaunchTFSHelper.CreateAndLinkWebPORTasks(domePORID);
            TempData["formState"] = "Created";
            //UpdateorInsertPORTasks(featureWorkItemId, domePORID);
            return View("WorkItemCreator");
        }` This is the Action i am calling.

Comment: What does that have to do with anything (and put your code in the question - not in comments). There is no point setting `TempData` in your `CreateWorkItems()` method - your making an ajax call which says in the same page. And since you don't even do anything in the success callback, there is no point returning a view - you don't do anything with it.

Comment: Just remove you `if` block in the view and create an empty label. Then in the controller, `return Json("your message here");` and in the ajax call add `success: function(response) { errorLabel.text(response); }`

Comment: But the rest of the code is awful. Use a view model with a property for `porTextBox`, add a `[Required]` attribute so you get client and server side validation, and handle the forms submit event (although its not really clear why you want to stay on the same page after posting the data)

Comment: Returning the Json object worked @StephenMuecke  !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The reason may be because page is not refreshing to render the label.

Exactly. You do an Ajax request to the server with JQuery(client script) and expect that the Razor code (server code) was executed to display the label. This doesn't work, because the server code doesn't know anything about the client code.

The solution is to display the label via JQuery. Render it by default, but hide it with CSS (display:none). After the request was successful, you can show the label by setting the CSS display property to "block" or "inline" using JQuery.